# JPA @manytomany unidirectional mapping

Tags: hibernate, jpa, many-to-many

When I try remove ExternalDataStorage  This query throw a constraint violation exception with  constraint name null .ExternalDataStorage has no relation mapping on it.Query first check ExternalTasks whichs contain ExternalDataStorage(Which will be removed) in ExternalTask's externalsources List and remove from list, if  list is empty remove externaltask and finally remove ExternalDataStorage entity(Target entity).

```
      public boolean deleteExternalDataStorage(Long sid) {
     EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
    EntityTransaction et = em.getTransaction();
    try {
        et.begin();
        ExternalDataStorage s = em.find(ExternalDataStorage.class, sid);
        List<ExternalTask> tasks = (List<ExternalTask>) em.createQuery("SELECT t FROM ExternalTask t ").getResultList();
        for (ExternalTask t : tasks) {
            if (t.getExternalSources().contains(s)) {
                t.getExternalSources().remove(s);
                if (t.getExternalSources().isEmpty()) {
                    em.remove(t);
                } else {
                    t = em.merge(t);
                }
            }
        }
        em.remove(s);
        et.commit();
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();


    } finally {
        if (et.isActive()) {
            et.rollback();
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

@Entity
public class ExternalTask implements Serializable {

```
@ManyToMany(cascade={CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.REFRESH})
@JoinTable(name = "ExternalTask_ExternalSource", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "TID"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "EXID"))
private  List<ExternalDataStorage> externalSources =new ArrayList<ExternalDataStorage>();


@ManyToMany(cascade={CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.REFRESH})
@JoinTable(name = "ExternalTask_Archive", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "TID"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "AID"))
protected  List<Archive> archives=new ArrayList<Archive>();


@ManyToOne
private User  ownerUser;
```

_*EDIT****_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*___**

I change query a little for delete case but problem still there

```
  EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
        EntityTransaction et = em.getTransaction();
        try {
            et.begin();
            ExternalDataStorage s = em.find(ExternalDataStorage.class, sid);
            List<ExternalTask> tasks=(List<ExternalTask>) em.createQuery("SELECT t FROM ExternalTask t ").getResultList();
           for(ExternalTask t:tasks) {
              if(t.getExternalSources().contains(s)){
                 t.getExternalSources().remove(s);
                  t= em.merge(t);
                  if(t.getExternalSources().isEmpty()){
                      em.remove(t);
                  }
               }
           }                 
            em.remove(s);
            et.commit();
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();


        } finally {
            if (et.isActive()) {
                et.rollback();
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

This is exception

```
**377249 [http-8080-2] WARN  org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter  - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null
377249 [http-8080-2] ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter  - Batch entry 0 delete from ExternalSource where EXID=6 was aborted.  Call getNextException to see the cause.
377249 [http-8080-2] WARN  org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter  - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 23503
377249 [http-8080-2] ERROR org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter  - ERROR: update or delete on table "externalsource" violates foreign key constraint "fk755287f526733b01" on table "externaltask_externalsource"
  Detail: Key (exid)=(6) is still referenced from table "externaltask_externalsource".
377250 [http-8080-2] ERROR org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener  - Could not synchronize database state with session
org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
        at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:71)
        at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:249)
        at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:235)
        at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:144)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:298)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:27)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1000)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:338)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:106)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:54)
    at com.endersys.itap.ui.module.storage.StorageManager.deleteExternalDataStorage(StorageManager.java:351)
    at com.endersys.itap.ui.module.storage.ExternalDataStorageEditorBean.delete(ExternalDataStorageEditorBean.java:73)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:172)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:276)
    at com.sun.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:68)
    at javax.faces.component._MethodExpressionToMethodBinding.invoke(_MethodExpressionToMethodBinding.java:78)
    at org.apache.myfaces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:57)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:127)
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxActionComponent.broadcast(AjaxActionComponent.java:55)
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processEvents(AjaxViewRoot.java:329)
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.broadcastEventsForPhase(AjaxViewRoot.java:304)
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processPhase(AjaxViewRoot.java:261)
    at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processApplication(AjaxViewRoot.java:474)
    at org.apache.my**faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationExecutor.execute(InvokeApplicationExecutor.java:32)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:103)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:76)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:183)
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.MyFacesServlet.service(MyFacesServlet.java:103)
    at com.endersys.itap.ui.MyFacesServletWrapper.service(MyFacesServletWrapper.java:34)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter.doFilter(ExtensionsFilter.java:341)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:206)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:290)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:388)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:515)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.endersys.itap.ui.MenuFilter.doFilter(MenuFilter.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:852)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
```

Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Batch entry 0 delete from ExternalSource where EXID=6 was aborted.  Call getNextException to see the cause.
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement$BatchResultHandler.handleError(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:2537)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1328)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:351)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeBatch(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:2674)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:48)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:242)
        ... 55 more
javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while commiting the transaction
        at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:71)
        at com.endersys.itap.ui.module.storage.StorageManager.deleteExternalDataStorage(StorageManager.java:351)
        at com.endersys.itap.ui.module.storage.ExternalDataStorageEditorBean.delete(ExternalDataStorageEditorBean.java:73)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
        at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:172)
        at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:276)
        at com.sun.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:68)
        at javax.faces.component._MethodExpressionToMethodBinding.invoke(_MethodExpressionToMethodBinding.java:78)
        at org.apache.myfaces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:57)
        at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:127)
        at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxActionComponent.broadcast(AjaxActionComponent.java:55)
        at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processEvents(AjaxViewRoot.java:329)
        at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.broadcastEventsForPhase(AjaxViewRoot.java:304)
        at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processPhase(AjaxViewRoot.java:261)
        at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processApplication(AjaxViewRoot.java:474)
        at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationExecutor.execute(InvokeApplicationExecutor.java:32)
        at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:103)
        at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:76)
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:183)
        at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.MyFacesServlet.service(MyFacesServlet.java:103)
        at com.endersys.itap.ui.MyFacesServletWrapper.service(MyFacesServletWrapper.java:34)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter.doFilter(ExtensionsFilter.java:341)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:206)
        at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:290)
        at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:388)
        at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:515)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at com.endersys.itap.ui.MenuFilter.doFilter(MenuFilter.java:169)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:852)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
        at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:71)
        at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:249)
        at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:235)
        at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:144)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:298)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:27)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1000)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:338)
        at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:106)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:54)
        ... 47 more
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Batch entry 0 delete from ExternalSource where EXID=6 was aborted.  Call getNextException to see the cause.
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement$BatchResultHandler.handleError(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:2537)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1328)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:351)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeBatch(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:2674)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:48)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:242)
        ... 55 more

```
And this is constraint on table



ALTER TABLE externaltask_externalsource
  ADD CONSTRAINT fk755287f526733b01 FOREIGN KEY (exid)
      REFERENCES externalsource (exid) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION;
```

Comment: ExternalSource And ExternalDataStorage  are same entity there is a name hell.Sorry...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add join fetch and problem solved.

```
public boolean deleteExternalDataStorage(Long sid) {
        EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
        EntityTransaction et = em.getTransaction();

        try {
            et.begin();
            ExternalDataStorage s = em.find(ExternalDataStorage.class, sid);            
            List<ExternalTask> tasks=(List<ExternalTask>) em.createQuery("SELECT t FROM ExternalTask t join fetch t.externalSources").getResultList();
           for(ExternalTask t:tasks) {
              if(t.getExternalSources().contains(s)){
                      t.getExternalSources().remove(s);
                  if(t.getExternalSources().isEmpty()){
                      em.remove(t);
                  }
               }
           }       
            em.remove(s);
            et.commit();
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
             if (et.isActive()) {
                et.rollback();
            }

        } finally {

        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Find it little bit hard to understand the question. I'm assuming you are looking for the externalsources to be removed when you remove the externaltask entity. I think for that you need to include REMOVE in your cascade settings or basically cascade={CascadeType.ALL}

EDIT:
Think I found the answer to your situation. When the many to many is wired the PP creates an integrity constraint on the db (I'm thinking you are doing an auto gen of the schema from the entities).

In this case SOURCE_TASK table where the relationship between source and task is held, has a foreign key relationship towards SOURCE table. So when you try to remove something from SOURCE table the underlying db gives a sql exception. I was able to reproduce your issue.

Solution:
What I did was I removed the foreign key constraint and I was able to remove the source entity fine.

As I originally stated for the TASK to SOURCE removal
If you remove the TASK entity with Cascade.ALL it should remove the entries everywhere.

Update: I'm thinking there is something in the way you are dealing with equality among your SOURCE objects. The List.contains(o) will be true if at least one object that is 'equal' is found. The List.remove(o) will remove the first occurrence of an object that 'equals' o. So I bet there are multiple occurrences of 'equal' objects inside the list.

Comment: @OpenSource sorry my question is not clear .I wantto remove ExternalSource(ExternalDataStorage) but if there is any task contain only this externalsource in it list i want to remove this task also.

Comment: By the way Removing a ExternalTask musnt remove any externalSource.

Comment: for your second comment you should be using CascadeType.ALL for the remove to cascade. For the first comment let me do a small program and get back to you. In the meantime where exactly is your exception happening? - the stack trace.

Comment: @OpenSource When commiting transaction exception occurs.If a comment    em.remove(s);  no exception occur but transaction isAlive return true so roolledback.

Comment: @OpenSource i think it is natural to middle table to hold keys to task and source tables a reference .But in query i am removing this key .Because i am removing source from task and there is cascade at merge .But it is true  for case when removing task .But for merge problem  still there.By the way thanks for kind reply.

Comment: I understand your point correctly now. But in my tests I'm able to merge and remove fine. Basically if the link is broken prior to the remove operation I'm not getting any exceptions. Let me know if you need the code and things like that if that will help some.

Comment: @Opensource I retest with more than one task and one externalsource problem still there But i think you test with single task and single source because it is only work then.

Comment: Problem is why a record still exist on join table(externaltask_externalsource) after task merged.